# Fear of shmitta and 10 year loans

Tags: borrowing, shmita, parashat-reeh, maseches-makos

The Gemara Makkos [3b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=3b&format=pdf) says:

> א"ר יהודה אמר שמואל המלוה את חבירו לעשר שנים אין שביעית משמטתו ואע"ג דאתי לידי לא יגוש השתא מיהא לא קרינן ביה לא יגוש

If someone who makes a loan only payable in 10 years, the loan survives Shmittah because it wasn't collectible at the time of Shmittah.

This is the Halacha as brought in Rambam (Shmittah VeYovelos [9:9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/7709.htm)) and Shulchan Aruch (Choshen Mishpat [67:10](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=cm_x9021)).

However, the Torah [says (Devorim 15:9)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9979/jewish/Chapter-15.htm#showrashi=true&v=9):

> הִשָּׁמֶר לְךָ פֶּן יִהְיֶה דָבָר עִם לְבָבְךָ בְלִיַּעַל לֵאמֹר קָרְבָה שְׁנַת הַשֶּׁבַע שְׁנַת הַשְּׁמִטָּה וְרָעָה עֵינְךָ בְּאָחִיךָ הָאֶבְיוֹן וְלֹא תִתֵּן לוֹ

That someone may say Shmittah is close, so I won't lend - this is an aveirah. (I have also heard this explain the idea of a Pruzbel - since Shmittah is rabbinic today, but not lending is Min HaTorah, so the Chachamim established a Pruzbel to prevent violating the Torah prohibition).

But if the loan can be made valid after Shmittah simply by making a longer term what is the problem? If the person is concerned about Shmittah, just make the term last past it. Why is this a problem?

<sup>It seems difficult to say that he wants the loan back close to the end of Shmittah, and will be worried he will be stuck in collections, as he can just avoid the problem by extending the term slightly anyway.</sup>

Comment: Not lending is seemingly only Min HaTorah when Shemitta is Min HaTorah, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA What??

Comment: @Ypnypn How can there be a biblical prohibition on not lending for fear of Shemitta if there is no Shemitta?

Comment: @DoubleAA Both Shemitta and the prohibition on not lending are Min HaTorah.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the requirement to lend isn't only this posuk. Sure, it may only be one aveirah (a bittul Aseh, I guess) instead of two, I don't know.

Comment: @Ypnypn Nowadays most assume Shemitta is only rabbinic.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the question is discussing about back when Shemitta was Min HaTorah.

Comment: @Ypnypn Perhaps, but the following parenthetical wasn't: _(I have also heard this explain the idea of a Pruzbel - since Shmittah is rabbinic today, but not lending is Min HaTorah, so the Chachamim established a Pruzbel to prevent violating the Torah prohibition)_

Comment: In order to extend a loan so that the loan is no longer overdue but is instead an extension requires both lender and borrower to agree to the new terms. The borrower who can't pay is better off not agreeing to an extension when shmita approaches since shmita will erase his loan completely.

Comment: @yoni, I'm thinking more in the context of origination of the loan. Sure, the borrower may say let's make the loan end on the 29th of elul, but is that really the case contemplated here?

Comment: Suppose shmitah is in 2 years and I want to make a loan to you payable in one year. I will be worried that you may not repay the loan when it's due and instead be late and shmita will erase the loan. I can't extend the due date unilaterally past shmita without your consent which you are incentivized not to agree to and besides I want to be paid now. I will lose the loan in that and anycontext where the loan is due and unpaid on time.

Comment: @Yoni, right, so I am saying make the loan for 2 years and a day from the beginning. Problem solved. Yes, the borrow has to agree, but since this is something only good for him, it seems difficult to say this is the case contemplated. But maybe.

Comment: I will be fearful to loan you if I have my doubts that if you don't pay on time and don't agree to a loan extension past shmita I will lose my money. I don't see your question...

Comment: @Yoni, so you are saying it is like adding a condition that Shmitta won't apply? Maybe, but it puts the loan further out than the verse would imply. It isn't because it is close, it is because it is medium-close, or perhaps even because it is far. If it were close, a reasonable term loan would extend past shmitta.

Comment: Stam halvaah shloshim yom. If shmitah is coming I'll be fearful to lend. I can't count on being able to extend the loan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chinuch ([580](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01644_all.html#HtmpReportNum0479_L2)) addresses a slightly different but related question:

> ואולי יעלה במחשבתך בני לאמר, ואיך ימנע אדם מהלואה לעולם מפני זה, ולמה נכתב על זה לאו, והלא בידו להתנות עמו על מנת שלא תשמיטנו בשביעית, וכדרך שאנו עושין תמיד בשטרותינו? אל יבהילך דבר זה, כי התורה תזהירנו בדברים, ואף על פי שאפשר בתקנות ותנאים.‏
>   And perhaps you, my son, might think to say: how could someone ever refrain from lending because of [fear of Shemitta]? Why is there a prohibition about this written, for he is able to stipulate with [the borrower that the loan is given] on the condition that Shemitta does not cancel the loan, like we do in all of our documents? This should not concern you, for the Torah warns us about things even if there are ways of [avoiding the issue] through enactments or stipulations. (my translation)

Comment: Not too satisfying, I know.

Comment: Interestingly, he also says it applies even when Shmittah is rabbinic. But this question bothered me less because this is a stipulation that the borrower has to agree to. He may not, but you have lend anyway. Extending the term, on the other hand, is to the borrower's advantage. Anyway +1 for the answer and the comment.